# How to configure camel rest request timeout

Tags: apache-camel, jetty-9

I have the following camel rest configuration

```
    <restConfiguration component="jetty" bindingMode="json" host="localhost"  port="{{server.port}}">
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
    </restConfiguration>

    <rest path="/copy" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
        <post uri="/copy-file" outType="java.lang.String" type="com.company.User">
             <to uri="bean:fileCopyService?method=copyFileService" />
        </post>         
    </rest>
```

How can I change the request timeout for this endpoint ? I would like to increase the timeout, by default jetty set to 3000 ms.

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution, you can put the following configuration inside restConfiguration `<camel:endpointProperty key="continuationTimeout" value="60000"/>`